# How to disassembly multiple functions using Linux utility objdump?

Tags: shell-script, gcc, binary, gdb, assembly

After a program is compiled and the binary file is generated, we can use `objdump` to disassemble the binary file and extract the assembly code and a lot of information.

However, using `-j .text` with `objdump`, it will disassembly the whole functions (glibc, OS functions, etc ... ) that I do not want.

I want to focus only on my own functions in the binary file. Using `nm`, it is possible to find only the user defined functions. After extracting the name of these functions, I want to disassembly only these functions. However, I do not want to search in the hug dump file that `objdump` generates it and extract disassembly code that related to my functions.

Assuming we have the binary file for `basicmath` program from **MiBench benchmark.**

using `nm`, it is possible to find only the functions that are defined in the source code of this program.

The command below will show the functions that I want (the user-defined functions)

```
nm -P tst.o | awk '$2 == "T" && $1 != "main" {print "b " $1}'
```

The result will be (considering `basicmath` program)

```
b deg2rad
b rad2deg
b solveCubic
b usqrt
```

Now, I need a way to tell objdump to disassembly only these functions and write the result to a single file.

Comment: Please provide a direct link to basicmath

Comment: it is not matter what a binary file we use, I just need a way to disassemble user-defined functions (not all the binary file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a way to tell the objdump program from binutils or elfutils to limit disassembly to specific functions. There are a couple of workarounds, though.

Assume the list of functions we're interested in is in file `list`:

```
$ nm -P basicmath_small |
    awk '{ if ($2 == "T" && $1 != "main" && substr($1,1,1) != "_") print $1}' > list
$ cat list
deg2rad
rad2deg
SolveCubic
usqrt
```

- use awk to filter the big disassembly output from objdump. Each region of interest starts with a line that ends with `<functionname>:` and continues until an empty line (or end-of-file).

```
$ xargs < list | sed -e 's/^/<(/' -e 's/ /|/g' -e 's/$/)>:\$/' > rlist
$ cat rlist
<(deg2rad|rad2deg|SolveCubic|usqrt)>:$
$ objdump -d -j .text basicmath_small | awk -v rlist="$(cat rlist)" \
    '{ if ($0 ~ rlist) doprint=1; if ($0 == "") doprint=0; if (doprint) print }'

0000000000400fc0 <rad2deg>:
  400fc0:       f2 0f 59 05 c8 4d 0a    mulsd  0xa4dc8(%rip),%xmm0        # 4a5d90 <c2+0x10>
  400fc7:       00
  400fc8:       f2 0f 5e 05 b8 4d 0a    divsd  0xa4db8(%rip),%xmm0        # 4a5d88 <c2+0x8>
  400fcf:       00
  400fd0:       c3                      retq
  400fd1:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  400fd6:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  400fdd:       00 00 00
0000000000400fe0 <deg2rad>:
  400fe0:       f2 0f 59 05 a0 4d 0a    mulsd  0xa4da0(%rip),%xmm0        # 4a5d88 <c2+0x8>
  400fe7:       00
  400fe8:       f2 0f 5e 05 a0 4d 0a    divsd  0xa4da0(%rip),%xmm0        # 4a5d90 <c2+0x10>
  400fef:       00
  400ff0:       c3                      retq
  400ff1:       66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  400ff8:       00 00 00
  400ffb:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
0000000000401000 <SolveCubic>:
  401000:       f2 0f 5e c8             divsd  %xmm0,%xmm1
...
```

- use the [objdump from Go](https://golang.org/cmd/objdump/), which takes a `-s regexp` option

```
$ xargs < list | sed -e 's/^/^(/' -e 's/ /|/g' -e 's/$/)\$/' > rlist
$ cat rlist
^(deg2rad|rad2deg|SolveCubic|usqrt)$
$ go tool objdump -s "$(cat rlist)" basicmath_small

TEXT rad2deg(SB)
  :0                    0x400fc0                f20f5905c84d0a00        MULSD 0xa4dc8(IP), X0
  :0                    0x400fc8                f20f5e05b84d0a00        DIVSD 0xa4db8(IP), X0
  :0                    0x400fd0                c3                      RET

TEXT deg2rad(SB)
  :0                    0x400fe0                f20f5905a04d0a00        MULSD 0xa4da0(IP), X0
  :0                    0x400fe8                f20f5e05a04d0a00        DIVSD 0xa4da0(IP), X0
  :0                    0x400ff0                c3                      RET

TEXT SolveCubic(SB)
  :0                    0x401000                f20f5ec8                DIVSD X0, X1
...
```